# Is it possible to use JExample and Spring integration test at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm testing a Spring web MVC application with heavy RESTful invocation that POST and DELETE a remote resource on demands.

When I'm trying to run integrated test, obviously I need to test POST first and then DELETE second. Unfortunately JUnit doesn't support such dependency test, and the vanilla JExample class cannot be run with Spring application context. Is there a feasible way of using both?

Comment: I’m the author of JExample, please get in touch we me so we can work together to get JExample runnig with Spring. My email is akuhn@iam.unibe.ch